# How to style the tick mark checkbox using css without using images?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Is there any way to style the tick mark checkbox only by using HTML and CSS3 without using images, like in Google's signin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a combination of HTML, CSS and jQuery. See the code I whipped up here to create a checkbox from an `<a>` tag and style it with CSS.

I've tested this code and it works beautifully in Chrome, FF, & IE 7-10. Haven't tested Safari or Opera...

http://jsfiddle.net/wdews/reXL6/

Just make sure you nest your `<a>` checkbox tag in `<form>` tags, give it an ID, a class of "checkbox", and hashtag HREF. In essence:

```
    <form action="#" method="get">

    <a class="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" href="#"></a>

    -or-

    <a class="checkbox checked" id="myCheckbox" href="#"></a>

    </form>
```

Let me know how that goes for you.

Comment: Very nice. My understanding of the question was that he particularly wants to style an html input/checkbox control without images, which can't be done. But this is a very tidy input replacement.

Comment: I appreciate it. I had actually been looking for a fully styleable solution for checkboxes in the past and this is what I came up with. I'm sure there are several things that could be improved upon, but in any case, I hope it serves those who need to style checkboxes!

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but this is what i suggest:

Associate labels to your checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="c1" />
<label class="check" for="c1"></label>
```

Hide by css your checkboxes:

```
.checkboxes input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none
}
```

Style the label as you want to. I created a simple jsfiddle that fully demonstrate how to use personnalise checkboxes.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KTADZ/1/) is the jsfiddle